# Why is CodeRush inconsistent in detecting which namespace aliases are necessary?

Tags: visual-studio, namespaces, alias, excel-interop, coderush

I had this:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
. . .
private Excel.Application _xlApp;
private Excel.Workbook _xlBook;
private Excel.Sheets _xlSheets;
private Excel.Worksheet _xlSheet;
```

CodeRush said the "Excel." for _xlBook, _xlSheets, and _xlSheet (but not _xlApp) was superfluous ("Redundant type qualifier"), so I removed them:

```
private Excel.Application _xlApp;
private Workbook _xlBook;
private Sheets _xlSheets;
private Worksheet _xlSheet;
```

Then, though, on trying to compile, I got err msgs like:

*The type or namespace name 'Sheets' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

So following CodeRush's recommendation broke the build (it was easy to revert back, of course, to a compiling state), but more interesting to me is why it didn't also recommend I remove the "Excel." from "Excel.Application _xlApp"

Why does it recognize that the "Excel." prefix is needed for Application, but not for Workbook, Sheets, and Worksheet?

### UPDATE

FWIW, other recommended changes by CodeRush also broke my build (noted below); additionally, it added acres of blank spaces to various places in my code when I ran "Code Cleanup" or some such command. I have uninstalled CodeRush. For my money, Resharper is a clear and decisive prevailer when comparing the two tools.

Another instance (no pun intended) where CodeRush didn't realize when a namespace needed a prefix was with this:

```
namespace RoboReporter.DeliveryPerformance
{
    public class DeliveryPerformance
```

...it advised removal of "RoboReporter." like so:

```
namespace DeliveryPerformance
{
    public class DeliveryPerformance
```

...but when I did that it thought that a reference to DeliveryPerformance (specifically, "List<DeliveryPerformance>") was pointing, not to the class, but to the namespace.

Comment: Are you using CodeRush for Roslyn - install via Tools|Extensions and updates. They're re-implementing in a very clean fashion and IME the levels of bugs of the nature you're talking about is pretty minimal (and they have always been good in fixing ones you report)

Comment: No, I was using the "normal" trial version; as I mentioned, R# is, in my opinion, considerably better than CodeRust, so I'll stick with it for sure.